# Service Connection

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

From the Android doc:

> Android system creates the connection between the client and service,
>   it calls onServiceConnected() on the ServiceConnection. The
>   onServiceConnected() method includes an IBinder argument, which the
>   client then uses to communicate with the bound service.

Does the Android system call `onServiceConnected()` using the client thread message queue?

Comment: In android, everything uses the UI thread unless explicitly mentioned.  All lifecycle methods especially.  Services are not new threads, they're just different contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diving around a little bit in the source code, the handler that is used to post the connection runnable callback is running on the main thread.

[Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/LoadedApk.java#LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher%28android.content.ServiceConnection%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.os.Handler%2Cint%29)

Also the [java doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) in the top of the class says

> Like many callbacks from the system, the methods on this class are called from the main thread of your process.